# Concatenate in Liquid markup Jekyll

Tags: ruby, json, jsonp, jekyll

I am having a file in my github repository, I have to use this file data in my angular application so I am making a $http() call and trying to get the data in JSONP format to avoid CORS issue.

So my problem is how to prepare I want to prepare JSONP data from my Jekyll post.

here is my code for file in GitHub:-

```
foo({
  "meta": {
  "status": 200,
  "X-RateLimit-Limit": "5000",
  "X-RateLimit-Remaining": "4966",
  "X-RateLimit-Reset": "1372700873",
},
  "data": [

    {% for post in site.posts %}
    { "text": {{ post.title | jsonify }}, "href": "{{ site.url }}/{{ post.url }}" },
    {% endfor %}

  ]
})
```

The Problem is when I call the above file, I get an error in my Liquid markup code saying `undefined token at:- {%`

But when I remove the code then I put some harcoded data like:-

```
"data":  
  { "text": "test", "href": "https://google.com" }
```

everything works fine.

What i want is to put jekyll post in my json data something what i am trying to do:-

```
"data": [

  {% for post in site.posts %}
  { "text": {{ post.title | jsonify }}, "href": "{{ site.url }}/{{ post.url }}" },
  {% endfor %}

]
```

ANY Help.....???

Thanks in advance,
Vishesh.

Comment: Is it possible to see your Github repository ?

Comment: Sorry David but i cant share my repository as it is my company official repository.. Actually i solved the issue myself.. I was getting the dude to some extra space that i gave after curly brace     {  "text"  ... So i was getting the error in client side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry David but i cant share my repository as it is my company official repository.. Actually i solved the issue myself..

I was getting the dude to some extra space that i gave after curly brace { "text" ... So i was getting the error in client side.

Comment: You shouldn't reply a comment with an answer, right?

Comment: @artu-hnrq - Ya, My bad .I was new to Stack Overflow 6 years back. But, i don't think it is worth downvoting

Comment: Right, I can't remove my downvote, since you haven't edited the answer! But nice to have your comment here

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to concatenate string with Jekyll for me is to use append/prepend filters.